# iPad mini must be plugged in to turn on even if battery is fully charged

Tags: ipad, battery

When I press the button to turn on the iPad mini it is asking to be plugged in despite the fact the battery is fully charged. Once plugged in for a few seconds I can remove the plug and the iPad mini will boot up fine.

<sup>iOS 8.3</sup>

Comment: how old is the battery?

Comment: A couple of years I do not think there is anything wrong with the battery because once it starts to boot up I can unplug and use it on battery normally

Comment: OK, and how long can you run on battery?

Comment: A long time. It doesn't appear to be draining any faster than it normally did

Comment: So it is not the battery it self. What non standard apps do you have running?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it helps to do a soft reset:
hold the Power button and the Home button at the same time, keep holding, the unit will switch off, keep holding, then when you see the white apple logo let go and let the ipad start up normally.
Try again.

Comment: No a soft reset did not do the trick

Comment: Still having this issue